# How to force Octave to run a specified script upon open, every time?

Tags: octave, octave-gui

I found this GNU documentation, that says there's a setup file for Octave, but when I search my machine, I don't see it, and the related directories don't seem to exist either:

https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Startup-Files.html

My goal is to force Octave to open up and run the same file automatically, at launch, every time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried creating any of the specified files?

Comment: Yes, and I set the home directory to the containing folder, and it didn't work. This is a file that ostensibly already exists, in a specified folder, that I can't find on my machine.

Comment: Did you try `octaverc` or `startup.m`?

Comment: I looked for both, neither exists, so I created startup.m in the launch path, and it didn't do anything.

Comment: have you been able to locate `octave-home/share/octave/site/m/startup`?

Comment: No, It doesn't seem to exist on my machine. Are you able to find it?

Comment: " I set the home directory to the containing folder": That doesn't make sense to me. Your home folder is your home folder. What do you mean you set your home folder to be something else? What is your operating system? What is the output of `cd ~; pwd` from your octave? Where did you place the `.octaverc` file? What did you put in it? Are you sure you remembered the dot in front of the name? In what sense did it "not work"? Did it give an error? Did octave run at all? Did your machine crash? Did aliens invade holding "we are your friend" signs but shooting at the same time?

Comment: What OS are you running on? And note that it's `.octaverc` with a dot at the beginning, not plain `octaverc`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.